# Mesh deforms badly when in pose mode despite weight painting or using vertex groups

Tags: mesh, armature

[image]
this is after leaning the chest bone forward, it seems to leave so many vertices behind and stretches the mesh between the locked vertices. I have parented the mesh to the bones using automatic weights and attempted weight painting and using vertex groups on each bone but the problems still persists.

Comment: The phrase “tried using vertex groups on each bone” is like someone describing how a car wouldn’t start, and then saying “I even tried turning the ignition with the key in it.” It makes me think there’s something critical you’ve missed.

Comment: there must still be a problem with these vertices, you need to weight paint or assign to the right vertex group, you can also check what vertex group the vertex is part of in the N panel > Item > Vertex Weight. Or please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots I just uploaded the file. Weight painting hasn't worked. I tried using vertex groups on each individual bone but this didnt work either. also I dont see vertex weight under the item menu. Thanks for your help.

Comment: please share the link it gave you (URL)

Comment: @moonboots https://pasteall.org/blend/37cc621ac9bc464fa8975993882595dc

Comment: Why don't you join all the meshes (head, pants, body)? Also you need to Merge by Distance otherwise the parentage won't work. Then it works fine for me (you still need to weight paint the pants though)